# Integrating third party services with Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, stripe-payments, mailchimp

I'm creating an Angular application, i'm planning on using Firebase cloud functions and firestore for my database. 
I want to be able to use MailChimp and StripeApi , is this possible? if not should i use Express ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't securely call the MailChimp and Stripe APIs from client-side code. As far as I know both of these require that you provide certain credentials that give the caller more permission than you'll want your user to have. That's why you should run such code in a trusted environment, such as your laptop (during development), a server that you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase. The latter is a complete server-side system where you can run such code without having to spin up your own machines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, totally possible. As long as your 3rd party provides web integration, you can always invoke a Cloud function to handle that flow for you. Think of your cloud function as your server that would make the request to eg MailChimp.